# Limit(s) of a Sequence from the decimal expansion of $\pi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, reference-request, soft-question, pi

I found a statement in a book concerning the decimal expansion of $\pi$ that I do not really understand. The statement is my problem **number 2**, where problem number 1 really looks like a reference request. Here there is the setting.

> Take $\pi$, and construct a sequence $x_1 := 0.1$, $x_2 := 0.41$, $x_3
>  := 0.592$, etc, where for example the first element of the sequence is
>    the first digit of the decimal expansion of $\pi$, and the second element of the sequence corresponds to the second and the third digit of the decimal expansion of $\pi$.

**1.** Apparently, it has been proved somewhere that this sequence converges at least to a limit point. I would like to know if somebody knows about this result.

**2.** I do not really get how this sequence, if it converge (as it has been proved), can converge ***to more than one point***.

Is there somebody who can clarify point 2?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I rather suspect that what has been proved is that the sequence, which is bounded by $0$ and $1$, has a convergent subsequence (Bolzano-Weierstrass). Of course it would be possible to have subsequences which are convergent to different limits.

Comment: For a simpler example, consider $\frac12, \frac 34, \frac 18, \frac{15}{16}, \frac 1{32}, \frac {63}{64}, \frac1{128}\ldots$.  The sequence does not converge.  But it contains convergent subsequences, some of which converge to 0 ($\frac12, \frac18,\frac1{32}, \ldots$ for example) and some of which converge to 1 ($\frac34, \frac{63}{64}, \frac{1023}{1024}, \ldots$ for example.)  Your sequence may converge, or not, and whether it does is probably unknown.  But, like the nonconvergent example sequence I mentioned, it must have convergent subsequences.

Comment: The simplest example of all is the sequence $\{0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1, \ldots\}$ which has subsequences converging to both $0$ and to $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence is contained in $[0,1]$, which is a compact set. Sequences in a compact set must have at least an accumulation point. In other words, there is a convergent subsequence.

A sequence can have more than one accumulation point. For example:

$$0.1,0.6,0.01,0.51,0.001,0.501,0.0001,0.5001,\ldots$$

Comment: Thus, trying to *unpack* your answer, you mean that different subsequences can lead to different accumulation points. Right?

Comment: The sequence definied in your book is quite strange. My guts tell me that it is dense in $[0,1]$, that is, every point in $[0,1]$ is an acummulation point of the sequence. Of course, I haven't proved it. As a matter of fact, I couldn't even figure out where to start.

Comment: @Kolmin Yes, that is the point.

Comment: It is a biography (informal) of a mathematician. I found this informal statement, and I was puzzled because I could not see how a sequence could converge to more than one point. Retrospectively, I had to see immediately that the informal statement most probably was hiding a reference to *subsequences*.